# Is there a way to determine what version of a package is installed for a docker image?

Tags: docker

I'm creating an image from a Dockerfile where I install some packages.

e.g. with `wget` as an example package.

```
RUN apt-get update -y && \ 
  apt-get install -y --no-install-recommends wget
```

I want to always build with an up-to-date version of packages (that I don't have to manually specify), but I need to know what the version in the image – for a CI verification. Specifically I want it to pull in the latest package and my CI will notify me if the version has changed for a package.

Edit: looks like this is not possible (https://github.com/moby/moby/issues/29110).

Comment: See my answer at https://stackoverflow.com/a/72691961/2727750

Answer (score 1):

How about writing the packages to a file then in your CI scripts parse that file?

`apt list --installed > installed_packages`

`docker exec -it <mycontainer> cat installed_packages`